# Infinite loop with scanf in while loop

Tags: c

I'm a very beginner in C, and I'm trying to put a range in the numbers, but the infinite loop appears when a letter out of range is typed (for example: p). 
If I type a number out of range, it works. 
I read about and I think its a problem with the buffer and the function scanf, when I press "Enter" I include \n. So I tried to clean by scanning with a char, but didn't work.
I also tried to put a space (' ') before the %x, and didn't work.
The scanf it's been ignored after I put an invalid letter; if I put an invalid number, the program works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int validity, pos; //validity 0:not valid, repeat the loop; validity 1: valid number
    char enter;

    while (validity == 0) {
        printf("Player1 1, type the position in hexadecimal (1 to f):\n");
        scanf(" %x%c", &pos, &enter); //here, the number pos is already in decimal

        if (pos == NULL){
            pos = 99; //if the letter typed is improper, I set 99, because is out of range
        }

        if(pos<=15 && pos >=0){
            validity = 1;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid number, out of range\n");
            validity = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf(" %x%c", &pos, &enter)` before using `pos`.  Was it at least 1?

Comment: "I tried to clean by scanning with a char, but didn't work" - code does not do that.  `scanf()` only moves on to `"%c" ` if `"%x"` succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

The very first time in your loop, `validity` does not have a defined value at all.

It might be `1`, it might be `0`, it might be `65,532`.

You should assign it an initial value.

```
int validity = 0, pos; //validity 0:not valid, repeat the loop; validity 1: valid number
```

---

You declared `pos` as an `int`; it will never be `NULL`.  It will have integer values.

This line makes no sense:

```
if (pos == NULL){
```

You should initialize that variable as well.

```
int validity = 0, pos = 99; //validity 0:not valid, repeat the loop; validity 1: valid number
```

Comment: `NULL` is just a macro for zero. When it gets preprocessed, the line will just read `if (pos == 0) {` edit: although I do agree it should not be written this way, just pointing out it is technically valid

Comment: You're confusing the newbie.  `NULL` is not just a macro for zero, it also has the type `void*`, and a `void*` should not be compared to an `int` except in special circumstances.

Comment: You're right, I apologize. I promise my intent was pedagogical not pedantic

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have default values for primitive data types. Hence in the line

```
int validity, pos;
```

You should probably set `validity` to some default value like 0 so that the loop runs at least once no matter what the input is(valid or invalid). Alternatively using a `do while` loop in this situation seems to be a more logical decision.

```
do
{
 //Your code
} while(validity == 0);
```

In that case you won't have to worry about setting a default value to `validity`.

Also as @abelenky pointed out earlier, checking `pos` for `NULL` is a technically bad idea as well. You could as well just skip this part

```
if (pos == NULL)
{ 
  pos = 99;
}
```

As `pos` is declared to be `int`, if the value of `pos` doesn't lie between 0 and 15 then it is automatically declared invalid by this part of your code.

```
if(pos<=15 && pos >=0)
{ 
  validity = 1;
} 
else 
{ 
  printf("Invalid number, out of range\n");
  validity = 0;
}
```

Hence there is no need to make another block for checking it's validity.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the infinite loop is that if you input a letter, the "\n" that follows it is taken as the input of scanf(...) function within the next loop. So you can simply add "getchar()" to fix it.  Note the “\n” after a number is ignored.

Differently, when you type a number out of range, it can be resolve with hex, and you can print it to see. But the letter can't(must be between a-f).

You can reference this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   int validity=0, pos=99;
   while (validity == 0){
       printf("Player1 1, type the position in hexadecimal (1 to f):\n");      
       scanf("%x", &pos); 

       if(pos<=15 && pos >=0){
          validity = 1;
       }else {
          printf("Invalid number, out of range\n");
          getchar();
       }
   }
}
```

Good luck.